# What is `std::string_view::max_size()`?

Tags: c++, c++11

While creating a version of `std::basic_string_view` for a private project (choices made for me: C++11; no boost:: allowed; with a pinch of NIH, so no GSL either) I came to implementing `std::basic_string_view::max_size()` for which the standard (n4820 21.4.2.3 Capacity) simply says:

> Returns: The largest possible number of char-like objects that can be referred to by a basic_string_view.

Logically, this would be the maximum number that `std::basic_string_view::size_type` can represent: `std::numeric_limits<std::basic_string_view::size_type>::max()` which comes out at 18446744073709551615 on my platform where `size_type` is `std::size_t`.

I figured that, since I want to be compatible with the standard libraries, I should ensure that I arrive at the same number as other implementations. This is where I get lost.

Given that I have a `auto max_size = string_view{"foo"}.max_size()` then I get the following results:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+
| Library      | Result                   |
+--------------+--------------------------+
| libstdc++    | 4611686018427387899      |
| libc++       | 18446744073709551615     |
| boost 1.72.0 | 3                        |
+--------------+--------------------------+
```

If my interpretation is correct, then that means that libc++ and I agree on what the value should be. I feel that boost is completely wrong, since the specification for `max_size` is to return the largest possible number that **a**, not **this**, `string_view` can refer to. However, as noted in the comments, boost::string_view predates the standard and it is thus unfair to call it "completely wrong". Further, looking at the implementations of all three libraries libc++ returns

```cpp
numeric_limits<size_type>::max();
```

libstdc++ returns

```cpp
(npos - sizeof(size_type) - sizeof(void*)) / sizeof(value_type) / 4;
```

and boost returns:

```cpp
len_;
```

Basically, two implementations appear to be wrong, but the question is: which one is correct?

Comment: n4659 is the closest document to the current standard

Comment: The boost implementation most likely predates the standard. Calling it "wrong" for not following a standard that didn't exist is a bit strong.

Comment: I have some recollection that gcc limits the maximum size of an object for practical reasons,  you will probably find that it is impossible to create an object of that size (4 exabytes!). One reason to at least limit size to 2^63-1 is so that subtracting two pointers into the object doesn't cause undefined behaviour by exceeding `ptrdiff_t` limits. Perhaps you could check libstdc++ source code and see if there are relevant code comments

Comment: @M.M indeed, trying to do `new char[-1ul];` on a 32-bit system results in `error: size ‘4294967295’ of array exceeds maximum object size ‘2147483647’`.

Comment: @Mat, that is a fair point.

Comment: I always viewed the definition `max_size` as unimplementable ... The exact "largest possible number" depends on many things and is often impossible to query. So I'd say the return values of GCC and Clang are both reasonable. (3, on the other hand, is unacceptable if a std implementation does it)

Comment: I have come to the conclusion that this may be a case where `implementation defined` is probably needed. Especially when you take the `ptrdiff_t` comment in to consideration. Given that it seems to be a helper, would it not be preferable to have `max_size` defined as `static constexpr size_t max_size() noexpect`? Such that one can query the max size of a `string_view` without needing an instance. I can understand, given this, why Boost might have decided on their implementation; I wouldn't want to guess a reasonable limit for all platforms either. I might follow suit in my implementation.

Comment: If it's intended to be compile-time constant, then why is it a non-static member function? [This might be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137766/why-isnt-stdstringmax-size-a-compile-time-constant/13139088#13139088).

Comment: Interesting that you have the C++11 tag, since `std::string_view` was only introduced in **C++17**.

Comment: @n. pronouns' m. That was very interesting. In fact, that might be worthy of an answer one could accept?

Comment: If that's an answer, then the question is a dupe...

Comment: I asked what max_size of a string_view is in an attempt to find out what the value is supposed to represent. According to that answer it's just some value that doesn't really matter. If you consider that a duplicate, then fair enough :)

Comment: @Adrian Mole yes `string_view` is a C++17 feature, but it is a library feature that needs nothing of the newer language features. Thus implementable in C++11 if you extend the constructors to work with `std::string`.